# Is it possible (and if so, how) to convert a store bought "pickles in vinegar" to "pickles in sweetened vinegar"?

Tags: flavor, vinegar, pickling

In the past I've bought many pickled cucumbers and other veg, but a few weeks ago I bought pickled 'sandwich' cucumber slices ([similar to this](https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/products/262007753)) which were in sweetened vinegar and liked them much better; the key thing about these pickles is that they are in "sweet" vinegar rather than normal pickling vinegar which is quite sour.

I would like to know whether it's possible, and if so how I can do it, to take a jar of pickles I've bought in normal (sour, not sweetened) vinegar and sweeten it? Can I just add sugar to the vinegar they are in, in the jar? Will that have any effect? If it would have an effect, how long would I need to leave the sugar in there before eating them?

Comment: In the US, sweet pickles are often labeled "bread and butter pickles"  (I have no idea why they're called that, I assume it's a specific style of pickle)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, the difference between 'regular' pickles & 'Jewish' pickles is sugar & dill. [I honestly don't know what makes them Jewish, but my partner grew up in the Jewish community & that's what she calls them, so that's about as much research as I've done ;-)

So - you'd think that adding sugar & dill & leaving them for a while after that would be just fine… except that once opened, those pickles only have a 5-day fridge life. A 'regular' pickle has about 6 weeks, by comparison.

I think your best shot, in that case, would be to over-sugar a bit & see what they're like by tomorrow or the day after. Mainly the sugar will be on the outside. Some fresh dill might just infuse the liquid a bit overnight, but you don't really have the time to experiment much after that before they're no longer safe.

Answer (score 0):

Buy dill pickles with no sugar, cut them up as desired, and put them in a baggie.  Add pickling liquid to cover.  Then add Splenda and let the pickles sit overnight in the refrigerator.  Start with 1 pickle and 1/4 cup of sweetener, and adjust to your liking. Add seasonings as desired, like garlic, onion, red pepper, etc.